# Is it legitimate to apply reset logic to inputs only?

Tags: fpga, pll, reset, vco

Let us consider this module for FPGA implementation:

```
module ticker(input clk, input step_toggle, output [7:0] value);
  reg step_toggle2 = 0;
  reg step_toggle3 = 0;
  
  reg neutral = 0;
  reg [7:0] counter = 0;
  
  always @(posedge clk) begin
    step_toggle2 <= step_toggle;
    step_toggle3 <= step_toggle2;
    
    if (step_toggle3 != neutral) begin
      neutral <= step_toggle3;
      counter <= (counter + 1);
    end
  end
  
  assign value = counter;
  
endmodule
```

If we hook up `clk` to the output of a PLL, it may output more than
the supported frequency while it stabilizes. We can add a reset signal
thusly:

```
module ticker(input clk, input reset, input step_toggle, output [7:0] value);
  reg step_toggle2 = 0;
  reg step_toggle3 = 0;
  
  reg neutral = 0;
  reg [7:0] counter = 0;
  
  always @(posedge clk) begin
    if (reset) begin
      neutral <= 0;
      counter <= 0;
    end else begin
      step_toggle2 <= step_toggle;
      step_toggle3 <= step_toggle2;
      
      if (step_toggle3 != neutral) begin
        neutral <= step_toggle3;
        counter <= (counter + 1);
      end
    end
  end
  
  assign value = counter;
  
endmodule
```

I believe it's correct to not reset the synchronizer stages as that
would introduces multiplexers that may hinder the elimination of
metastability.

While it looks like `neutral`, `counter`, and `value` will be stuck at
0, I suspect this may not be the case. The reset logic can be thought
of as a 2:1 mux at the end of the normal logic. Thus if `step_toggle3`
transitions 0 -> 1 or 1 -> 0, it can cause glitches. If the clock
speed exceeds the time required for the logic to settle, erroneous
values might potentially be registered, and in the case of `counter`
propagate to the output on the next cycle. Of course things always get
restored on the next cycle but it's still an imperfection.

Now, let's add the reset in a different way:

```
module ticker(input clk, input reset, input step_toggle, output [7:0] value);
  reg step_toggle2 = 0;
  reg step_toggle3 = 0;
  reg step_toggle4 = 0;
  
  reg neutral = 0;
  reg [7:0] counter = 0;
  
  always @(posedge clk) begin
    step_toggle2 <= step_toggle;
    step_toggle3 <= step_toggle2;
    step_toggle4 <= (reset ? 0 : step_toggle3);
    
    if (step_toggle4 != neutral) begin
      neutral <= step_toggle4;
      counter <= (counter + 1);
    end
  end
  
  assign value = counter;
  
endmodule
```

This adds one cycle of delay, but also improves the timing achievable
as the reset logic is no longer on the main paths. As long as the PLL
period remains longer than the time required to propagate from a
register through a single multiplexer and then to another register,
it will work. There is no longer the possibility of glitches as the
`step_toggle4` input is fixed during PLL warmup, and the logic solves
statically; the clock rate for `neutral` and `counter` becomes
irrelevant. Importantly, for this work the logic can't contain a
counter that always ticks or anything similar; but this is not a big
limitation as most times there is a state machine with an idle state
that requires input to leave that state.

Regarding the PLL maximum speed, I've written a simple test program
for ECP5 that repeatedly starts and stops a PLL, and continuously
checks to see if the multiplexing stage worked. It has run for a few
hours now without identifying faults. Also, the timing report for a
single multiplexer seems to exceed the "VCO rate" parameter. I don't
know if the PLL output frequency can ever exceed the "VCO rate" or
not, elucidation of this point would be appreciated.

EDIT: I've become aware that many FPGAs, including the ECP5, have dedicated synchronous reset logic on the DFFs. This does not really change the nature of the question as it seems equivalent regardless whether the logic is in a LUT or in the DFF.

Currently I strongly prefer the second method, but, before using it, I thought I'd ask to see if anyone can see any flaw in it that I may
have overlooked.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @Community Pretty sure Community can't hear me but I thought I'd add that I moved the "question" paragraph to the end of the question for emphasis.

Answer (score 1):

In most PLLs, the output or the connection from the VCO to the output divider is gated with the PLL's `locked` signal, and even if it wasn't, the frequency would be roughly correct, so PLL startup is not normally a source of timing violations.

The `neutral` signal could just be called `step_toggle4` -- that's just one extra stage of synchronization, but you can also edge-detect between the second and third stage by comparing `step_toggle2` and `step_toggle3`.

The dedicated reset logic in DFFs is what you want -- implementing this kind of logic in LUTs means creating a latch, and there are worse issues than a bit of metastability with that. A reset should clear state, and LUTs should not have state.

Note that the `reset` signal needs to be deasserted synchronously to `clk`.